# How to save locally PDF or other files in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, save

I'm developing functions to read PDF and Save it locally on iPhone and iPad. I'm building this to iOS 6.1 and more, so I don't have any constraint for the SDK.

So, I wanna know what's the best and simple solution to write contents locally (whatever file).

Perhaps somebody knows a lib to do this functionality ?

Comment: I don't understand why I receive bad reputations... I can't ask questions here ?

Comment: Have you tried saving the PDF data to disk?

Comment: There is a library. It's called `NSFileManager`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer here : [Save your app data with NSCoding and NSFileManager](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/how-to-save-your-app-data-with-nscoding-and-nsfilemanager)

```
NSData *dataPdf = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:pdfOnline.url];

//Get path directory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

//Create PDF_Documents directory
documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PDF_Documents"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, @"**PUT FILENAME YOU WANT**"];

[dataPdf writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: That's is the solution, this is the solution of a guy that deleted his post just after, so I have written my own solution..Why bad reputations ?

Comment: Link-only answers are very fragile, since if the link breaks, the answer will have no content whatsoever. People often downvote to discourage such answers. A short summary of the linked article would go a long way.