# Download PDF from Resources Bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am able to successfully view a PDF from a website.
The code I am currently using:

```
PDFAddress = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.msy.com.au/Parts/PARTS.pdf"];
request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:PDFAddress];
[webView loadRequest:request];
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

However, I have added that pdf in my bundle resources and I want user to download it from there, by doing so, there is no network required. I wonder how it could be done?

Answer (score 0):

Make a url that points to your resource bundle

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"myPDF" withExtension:@"pdf"];
```

Comment: But that opens the pdf, not download.

Comment: Are you trying to get the pdf from the web and download it locally, and then access it?

Comment: I am not trying to get the pdf from the web. I have put that pdf in the main resource bundle, i want user to download it in his device.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082240/how-to-save-locally-pdf-or-other-files-in-ios